# Regression for multiple variables linked across time

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following data set I am trying to run a time series but am new to R and time series. The time is represented by t. The goal is to try to find the impact of X1-X5 on AverageSales (Y1) and Averagevisit (Y2) to see if any of them have an impact. X1-X5 vary by shop. My guess is that Y1 and Y2 are related to the Y1/Y2 at the time prior which is why I am trying to do a time series. Maybe I don't need a time series at all?

```
Shop= c(A, A, A, B, B, B)
X1=c(20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30)
X2= c(5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2)
X3= c(20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10)
X4=c( 15, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5)
t= c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30)

Y1 =c(3.464, 2.898, 2.52, 2.224, 1.896, 1.646)
Y2=c(9.354058058, 7.507103103, 5.991591592, 4.630454454,
               4.279463463, 3.590274274)
```

In my data, t is repeated from 1-2000 for every shop. I tried to use the `ts(data,freq... )`, but how do I set `t` to be the variable? `ts(data, frequency=1, start=1, end=2000)`? How do I then run the regression?

Comment: I don't see Y1 or Y2 in your data? Did you mean AverageSales and AverageVisit ?

Comment: Yes. sorry. will fix it

Comment: In the form shown in the question the data is panel data, not a time series.

Comment: Yes that's my current data-  I don't know how to convert it to a ts. Should I add a lag and run a regression on that?

Comment: When you say your data is repeated for 1-2000 for every shop, what do you mean exactly? And how many shops do you have? Just A and B?